# Why does Spring-data-redis use keys command when cache evict

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I use redis as my cache server when i use springboot.
But i read the spring-data-redis source, when evict cache, the code is

```
byte[][] keys = Optional.ofNullable(connection.keys(pattern)).orElse(Collections.emptySet())
                    .toArray(new byte[0][]);
```

Redis recommends replacing the keys command with the scan command. why does the spring team not do this.

Comment: Very good question.  The KEYS command does not scale, In our application cache eviction has become a bottleneck with KEYS taking 160ms and this blocks all other redis commands so cache evictions essentially block the entire distributed application cluster.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality isn't available in the current released version ([2.5.5](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/releases/tag/2.5.5)) and more likely will be included in the next release ([2.6.*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/BatchStrategies.java#L35))

> The cache implementation defaults to use KEYS and DEL to clear the
> cache. KEYS can cause performance issues with large keyspaces.
> Therefore, the default RedisCacheWriter can be created with a
> BatchStrategy to switch to a SCAN-based batch strategy. The SCAN
> strategy requires a batch size to avoid excessive Redis command
> roundtrips:

```
RedisCacheManager cm = RedisCacheManager.build(RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(
  connectionFactory, 
  BatchStrategies.scan(1000))
).cacheDefaults(defaultCacheConfig())
```

> Note: The KEYS batch strategy is fully supported using any driver and
> Redis operation mode (Standalone, Clustered). SCAN is fully supported
> when using the Lettuce driver. Jedis supports SCAN only in
> non-clustered modes.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/main/src/main/asciidoc/reference/redis-cache.adoc